# Trust anchor for certification path not found JMETER android testing

Tags: testing, jmeter

Hey im trying to do a mobile testing in JMeter, i've followed every step of [this guide](http://blogs.quovantis.com/mobile-performance-testing-using-jmeter/), and the recording works fine. The problem is that i have to record in a native app and when i try to log in i get the following error message:

> ```
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
> ```

Im not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why you're asking us and not the author of "this guide"?
2. These "every steps" are not complete, there is a couple more "every steps" which you need to "follow"

   - In the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your app [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) add the following entry:

     ```
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config
     ```
   - Add `network_security_config.xml` file to your application [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) folder and copy the below code there:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <network-security-config>
         <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
             <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
             <certificates src="user" />
          </trust-anchors>
         </debug-overrides>
       </network-security-config>
     ```
   - Re-compile your application in the [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode):

     ```
     gradlew assembleDebug
     ```
   - Replace the app you're trying to record with the debug .apk from the previous step
   - You should be able to record now

More information:

- [Android Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)
- [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)